# ebay api getting a large image

Tags: php, image, ebay-api

I'm using the following URL to search eBay:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindPopularItems&version=849&siteid=3&appid=app_id_removed8&MaxEntries=100&ItemSort=EndTime&ItemType=FixedPriceItem&IncludeSelector=SearchDetails&responseencoding=XML&QueryKeywords=breaking+bad&HideDuplicateItems=true&outputSelector=PictureURLLarge&descriptionSearch=false
```

It works, but the gallery images it returns are so small.

e.g.

http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/pict/2311096735168080_1.jpg

How can i make it return large images?

I've read this: [eBay API - How to get large item pictures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670068/ebay-api-how-to-get-large-item-pictures)

Which suggested I add `&outputSelector=PictureURLLarge&descriptionSearch=false` but I just get the same response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPI is an old API call and doesn't support a lot of the parameters that newer API calls allow, such as an output selector, item sorting, description search, etc.

To get larger images, you may need to use a simple brute force find/replace on the thumbnail URLs.

If you search/replace "8080_" with "4040_" or "9696_" you'll get larger images. Try it right now in your browser with any eBay item# and it should work.

See "eBay API Gallery Image Resizing" on my [eBay tech tips site](http://www.helios825.org/) for more info on this.

Comment: wow thanks! i didn't realise i was using an old API call, i'll look into using a more upto date one :) also I noticed i could pull in images by doing: http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/pict/<item_id>_1.jpg thanks for your help!